# How to configure nginx so that the web server only allow access via IP address and deny all access via domain name?

Tags: nginx

Suppose I have a web server running on the IP address **1.2.3.4** and the domain name **abc.com** resolves to **1.2.3.4**.  How shall I write the nginx.conf so that the web server only allows access via the IP address **1.2.3.4** and denies all access via the domain name **abc.com**?

nginx.conf:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  1.2.3.4;
    }
    ...
}
```

Currently I set **server_name** to **1.2.3.4**, and it seems that the web server is accessible via both **1.2.3.4** and **abc.com**.

Answer (score 1):

I would define two server stanzas. One for **abc.com** to which access is denied. Then define a catch-all server that can be accessed via ip address:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  abc.com;
    return       403;
}

server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To configure nginx to allow access only via the IP address and deny access via the other network, you can modify your configuration as follows:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name abc.com;

location / {
    allow 1.2.3.4;
    deny all;
}}
```

abc.com  access is allowed only for the IP address 1.2.3.4 and denied for all other IP addresses.

Make sure to replace 1.2.3.4 with the actual IP address of your server. Additionally, this configuration assumes that your website content is served from the root location ("/").